# Trying to put text in <select> with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

So I am trying to put the GET of the ajax request in the `<select>` using an id but it doesn't work. However when I use for example `<p>` with an id or `<option>` or anything else it does work and output what I want.

This is my Ajax script

```
    <script>
    function showUser(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("brand").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("brand").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","inc/parts_form2.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

This is a part of the form

```
Year: 
<select onchange="showUser(this.value)">
```

%year%
        
    
    Brand:

```
<select id="brand">

</select>
```

And this is my php

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];
echo $q;
?>
```

I am trying to get the output in `<select id="brand"></select>`. Which I check in the source code if it worked.

Comment: jQuery would make your life so much easier...

Comment: You can only have `<option>`s or `<optgroup>`s in a select no text or other tags.

Comment: I know but I check the text in the source code but I see nothing in it so it just doesnt output it in there

Comment: You were right it was because it wasnt in option tags, somehow it doesnt show up in the source code though. But thanks Ill try to go on from here. Sorry for the stupid question im new with Ajax

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the content in option tags inside the select tag.

```
"<option>"+xmlhttp.responseText+"</option">;
```

or in php :

```
$d = "<option>".$_GET['q']."</option">;
```

Comment: Thanks I have done it the last way and that worked. I thought it would be visible in the source but I noticed ajax doesnt change the source.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt the response text passed into the onreadystatechange callback?

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (response){

// insert your method body here

}
```